# Handling catch statements in typescript

Tags: typescript

In my code below, af is firebase object which makes a http call.
I am attempting to catch the errors. The code below works fine.

```
this.af.auth.login({
        email: formData.value.email,
        password: formData.value.password
      }).then(
          (success) => {console.log(success);}
      ).catch(
          (err: any) => {
            if (err.code.includes('user-not-found')) {
              this.error = "User not found. Invalid username/password";
            }
          }
      );
```

err is an object like below:

```
 err {
  code: 'auth/user-not-found',
  message: 'this user was not found'
 }
```

In order to give it a type I defined an interface as below:

```
interface Error {
  code: string;
  message: string;
}
```

and changed the catch statement as below:

```
  .catch((err: Error) => ...
```

However, typescript throws an error:

```
 typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 35 
            Argument of type '(err: Error) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Error) => any'. Types of 
            parameters 'err' and 'a' are incompatible. Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'Error'. Property 'code' 
            is missing in type 'Error'. 

      L34:  ).catch(
      L35:      (err: Error) => {
      L36:        if (err.code.inc
```

Comment: Does this change if you name it differently? Try `MyError` for example, `Error` is an existing native class.